# Flutter code is unable to compile and run in Linux (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64)

Tags: linux, flutter, ubuntu

**My device** : Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64

**Code** : Default Code generated by Flutter

**Project Location** : /media/mrinmoy/External (where *External* is my HDD with FAT32 format)

I generated a linux specific project using flutter. I used this code `flutter create --platform linux test_app` to generate my project.

But when I tried to run it , it gave some error and I am unable to find any solution regarding this error.

***I have checked the flutter site and verified that all the mentioned dependencies are installed in my system and all are in their latest versions***

**Debug Console (ERROR)** :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
main.dart:1
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/usr/bin/clang++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /media/mrinmoy/External/test_app/build/linux/x64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_a56ce && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a56ce.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    [2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_a56ce
    FAILED: cmTC_a56ce 
    : && /usr/bin/clang++   CMakeFiles/cmTC_a56ce.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_a56ce   && :
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


Exception: Unable to generate build files
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have raised an issue in Github-Flutter. Any details(Logs) regarding this will found in this following link : [GitHub-Flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/132696#issue-1853948139)

And here is my problem , I will be obiliged to get an detailed answer regarding this specific problem .

Comment: It looks like you don't have a complete development environment installed.  `sudo apt-get install build-essential` might help.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well I tried running your command , and the output was , build-essential is already the newest version (12.9ubuntu3). I guess that means it is already installed . But still getting the same problem .

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libstdc++-dev` should help, it makes `-lstdc++` work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed lstdc++ package.

```
sudo apt install libstdc++-12-dev
```